# return array of controls as aggregation in sap ui5

Tags: javascript, forms, sapui5, aggregation

I have a use case where I want to add two `sap.m.Input` controls in the `FormElement`. But I have certain conditions on which these two `Input` controls can be changed. As I have seen in many examples, `.bindAggregation` method returns only one control. Can I make it return array of controls?

```
var oInput1 = new sap.m.Input();
var oInput2 = new sap.m.Input();
var oInput3 = new sap.m.Input();

var oFormElement = new sap.ui.layout.form.FormElement();
oFormElement.bindAggregation("fields", "properties", function(sId, oContext){
    var value = oContext.getProperty("value");
    if (value > 5) {
        return [oInput1, oInput3];
    } else {
        return [oInput1, oInput2];
    }
});
```

I have written this sample but it show nothing. How to return array of controls in `.bindAggregation`. I was trying to use `HBox` in the fields, but it has a risk of causing the layout issues. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As _@corshdi_ mentioned you need to use the factory function. Below is the working example [Factory Function for sap.m.Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55022874/how-can-i-get-json-as-function-parameter-in-sapui5-m-table/55026179#55026179)

Answer (score 0):

You can't return multiple elements in your factory function. The factory function will be called for each context and must return exactly one element.

If you can't modify your service to return one context for each input, you might consider constructing your form in JavaScript instead of using data binding. This means to

1. request the `properties` from your service
2. loop through each property and add input(s) to the form element using the [`FormElement.addField`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.layout.form.FormElement/methods/addField) method.